# Mesh deformed after changing pose

Tags: rigging, armature, mirror

I've rigged a model and why I try to change the pose, the mesh deforms badly on the legs.

The model has a mirror modifier (on X and has Vertex Groups option checked) and the armature has X-Axis Mirror. Automatic weights was used and after that I've cleaned a bit the vertex groups (mainly in the head and arms).

But I cannot find what's happening with the legs.

[image: mesh in edit mode]

[image: weight painting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that the body/neck/head were having all the vertices on the right side, even though the mesh has a mirror modifier.

I've deleted half of the body/neck/head, deleted the vertex groups and the armature modifier and used Automatic weights again and now it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic weight issue. The vertices that aren't moving correctly are either weighted to the wrong bone, aren't weighted to a bone at all, or aren't weighted *enough* to the right bone.

Vertices follow the movement of the bone they're assigned to, but they can be assigned to only follow *a percentage* of a given bone's movement. For example, if you assign a vertex to a bone at 50% (or 0.5) and then rotate the bone 90 degrees, the vertex will only follow half of that movement... 45 degrees. Furthermore, you can assign a vertex to more than one bone. For example, you might assign a vertex on the knee to 50% on the lower leg and 50% on the upper leg so that smooths between both of them.

It looks to me like you have a handful of vertices on the (left?) leg that are not assigned to the bone going back to the left. Consequently, the bone moves to the left, but the vertices don't follow. A similar thing is probably happening with the ones on the right. Note: "not assigned to" might also mean "assigned to a *different* bone."

Interesting note: it's possible (depending on your Blender settings) to have a vertex with *more than 100%* total influence. Unless you have "[normalize all](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/weight_paint/weight_tools.html#normalize-all)" turned on, all the weights will get added together and do weird things.

Comment: I'll check where the vertices belong to. Thanks